# Specifications on Google Chrome's Cache Management and Portability Across Devices

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm attempting to run a web app entirely offline using the PWA mechanism.

Since I'm not fluent in English, I've written this in my native language and translated it. Apologies for any awkward phrasing.

Background:

I'm using two machines: Machine A (online) and Machine B (offline).
Machine A has a fresh installation of Google Chrome, while Machine B has no Chrome installed.

Steps:

Accessed a PWA site on Machine A.
Stored all generated cache files and the Chrome application itself on a physical device.
Connected Machine B to the device and transferred all files.
Tried accessing the same PWA site on Machine B.

Result:
Despite transferring everything, the web page didn't display on Machine B.

Environment:

Machine A/B: Apple M2, OS: macSonoma version 14.3/14.4
Browser: Google Chrome Dev version 125.0.6368.2, cache path:

`/Users/${username}/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome Dev/Default/*` and `/Users/${username}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome Dev/*`

Cache works offline on Machine A. This is the first Chrome Dev installation on both machines, no account linked.

Questions:

Is manual porting of cache resources technically feasible?
Are there files generated by Chrome outside the paths mentioned, and could transferring them replicate the cache resource environment on a different device?

Despite transferring everything, the web page didn't display on Machine B.